# Poor line quality withJS Graphics 2D Drawing

Tags: javascript, graphics2d, linewidth

I am dismayed at the poor quality of lines I draw in Graphics2D. When I draw a line with
`lineWidth=1` and `strokeStyle="black"` I would expect the line to look the same as the border of my canvas, which is `1px solid black`. But no, the line is (or at least looks) wider, and is kind of fuzzy and gray rather than black. See attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUCXA.jpg) which is the output of this code:

```js
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.strokeRect(3, 3, 150, 150);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Any ideas ? I am also intrigued by the (very faint) shadow lines on each side of the border as well as the drawn lines (admittedly you only see these when the image is enlarged).

Comment: I haven't done this in a while, but I have a vague memory of a 0.5 pixel offset fixing blurry lines on a canvas.

Comment: @DBS Thanks for your feedback ! That post offers a lot of different explanations and fixes, all but one of which did not work for me. But one post absolutely nailed it for me :
"I did it slightly differently I did context.translate(0.5, 0.5); before drawing and then context.translate(-0.5, -0.5); afterwards so I didn't have to add 0.5 to everything"

I can't say I really understand, but all of a sudden I have razor sharp lines of the correct width and hue ! Your recollection was correct, it seems. Hallelujah and thanks again :D